JS for CSS image slider box
I am finding an image box: preview and small preview list under the preview.

The html is as follow :
 <!--image list-->
        <div class="image-list-container d-flex">
          <div class="image-list-item cursor-pointer image-highlight">
            <div id="" class="">
              <div class="hv-centered"><!----><img class="show-img img-fluid" src="https://5.imimg.com/data5/NR/TP/MY-9295383/hcl-desktop-500x500.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-list-item cursor-pointer" >
            <div id="" class="">
              <div class="hv-centered"><!----><img class="show-img img-fluid" src="https://tiimg.tistatic.com/fp/1/007/341/shock-proof-black-color-medium-size-acer-desktop-computer--825.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image-list-item cursor-pointer" >
            <div id="" class="">
              <div class="hv-centered"><!----><img class="show-img img-fluid" src="https://cdn.britannica.com/97/155497-050-4C5BFFFC/laptop-computer.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
          <div class="image-list-item cursor-pointer add-image-section add-download-img p-0">
            <div id="ember519" class="dropdown btn-group h-100">
              <button class="btn file-upload add-download-img-btn" type="button">
                <input id="add-images-btn" title="" multiple="" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpg" class="upload form-control cursor-pointer" type="file" />
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="icon align-text-top action-icons icon-xlg fill-dropdown-blue">
                  <path d="M256 15C122.9 15 15 122.9 15 256s107.9 241 241 241 241-107.9 241-241S389.1 15 256 15zm122 263H278v100c0 12.2-9.8 22-22 22s-22-9.8-22-22V278H134c-12.2 0-22-9.8-22-22s9.8-22 22-22h100V134c0-12.2 9.8-22 22-22s22 9.8 22 22v100h100c12.2 0 22 9.8 22 22s-9.8 22-22 22z"></path>
                  <path fill="#FFF" d="M378 234H278V134c0-12.2-9.8-22-22-22s-22 9.8-22 22v100H134c-12.2 0-22 9.8-22 22s9.8 22 22 22h100v100c0 12.2 9.8 22 22 22s22-9.8 22-22V278h100c12.2 0 22-9.8 22-22s-9.8-22-22-22z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
              <button id="ember521" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-secondary rounded-start-0 add-download-img-btn no-border" type="button"></button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <button class="dropdown-item file-upload">
                  <input id="ember522" title="" multiple="" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpg" class="upload form-control cursor-pointer" type="file" />
                  Add More Images
                </button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-523="523">Download As ZIP</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/-->

I am still learning js in how to have the scenario, when each item list is clicked it will previewed in the box above. as well when the primary text is clicked.
the code is here text
Thank you for you help.

Here:
I have added the primary button but id didn't move it to on the top of previewing image. and i didn't add the delete button. i hope you can handle that.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Selector</title>
    <style>
      
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box; 
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
        }
        
       
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        
       
        .large-image {
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 2px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 8px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
        
        .large-image img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover; 
        }
        
       
        .image-row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: 10px;
            flex-wrap: nowrap; 
        }
        
       
        .image-row img {
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            object-fit: cover;
            border-radius: 8px;
            cursor: pointer; 
            border: 2px solid transparent; 
            transition: border-color 0.3s; 
        }
        
        .image-row img:hover {
            border-color: #333; 
        }
        .primary-button {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px; 
            right: 10px; 
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #007bff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
        }
        
        .primary-button:hover {
            background-color: #0056b3; 
        }
        .image-row img.selected {
            border-color: blue; 
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="large-image">
            <img id="mainImage" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/2096494657/photo/senior-couple-using-laptop-while-sitting-on-sofa-in-living-room-at-home.webp?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=6eNx4PV7PPg7LAZ9JNRFxvBg8pHHd_l7nvR3tx05hcQ=" alt="Selected Image">
 <button class="primary-button" onclick="makePrimary()">Primary</button>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="image-row" id="imageRow">
            <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/2039918088/photo/happy-african-american-woman-using-tablet-on-a-cozy-sofa-at-home.webp?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=gk4wDaG3UaQuvdWWUN0CoeJ_SzFujnMLcuzgp6JzaGI=" alt="Image 1" onclick="updateMainImage(this)">
            <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/2000672702/photo/happy-smiling-mature-indian-or-latin-business-man-ceo-trader-using-computer-typing-working-in.webp?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=PExSb0GIEAlbBm8wDtNucKJrVVJOTqn9kHEZvQBhzjU=" alt="Image 2" onclick="updateMainImage(this)">
            <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/2096494657/photo/senior-couple-using-laptop-while-sitting-on-sofa-in-living-room-at-home.webp?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=6eNx4PV7PPg7LAZ9JNRFxvBg8pHHd_l7nvR3tx05hcQ=" alt="Image 3" onclick="updateMainImage(this)">
            <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1500285927/photo/young-woman-a-university-student-studying-online.webp?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=w6oDn8-ru4jZhnnEt8AI6KdlgCJIgaaEZ4IMV50DnsQ=" alt="Image 4" onclick="updateMainImage(this)">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        
        let selectedImage = null;

        
        function updateMainImage(imgElement) {
            
            if (selectedImage) {
                selectedImage.classList.remove('selected');
            }
            
            
            selectedImage = imgElement;
            imgElement.classList.add('selected');
            
           
            var newSrc = imgElement.src;
            document.getElementById('mainImage').src = newSrc;
        }
        
        
        function makePrimary() {
            if (!selectedImage) return; 
            
            const imageRow = document.getElementById('imageRow');
            
            
            
            
            
            imageRow.prepend(selectedImage);
            
           
            var newSrc = selectedImage.src;
            document.getElementById('mainImage').src = newSrc;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>




@fawzan If this satisfies your query or requirements then please accept the answer and make it more visible for fellow devs.
